# SharpSVN: Set timeout on connecting an offline server

Tags: c#, svn, sharpsvn

I'm currently facing the problem that users try to connect to an offline SVN server (or simply use misspelled URLs). So I'd like to implement a cheap Ping(Uri) function.

I thought the follwing SharpSVN method might be the right approach:

```
SvnClient.GetInfo(SvnTarget, SvnInfoArgs, Collection<SvnInfoEventArgs>)
```

Unfortunetally the function **blocks about 25 seconds**! Is there a way to override the timeout programmatically? 2 or 3 seconds might be sufficient for me.

Thanks
Marcel